# Rails 4 pass multiple params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a shopping cart with `order_items`.  `OrderItem` has one `product_id` and multiple `book_ids`.  When I have multiple `order_items` i.e. two products, the `Order.create` only accepts the first `product_id`.

**The checkout form:**

```
  <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
    <h4><% current_order.subtotal %></h4>
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
    <script 
      class='stripe-button' 
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
      data-key="<%= @stripe_btn_data %>" 
      data-amount=<%= current_order.subtotal %> 
      data-description="<%= @order_items.count %>" 
      data-shipping-address="true"
      data-billing-address="<%= @stripe_btn_data %>"
    ></script>
    <% @order_items.each do |oi| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, oi.id %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Order.create inside of ChargeController**

```
def create

@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

Order.create(
  user: current_user,
  stripe_billing_name:                  params[:stripeBillingName],
  stripe_shipping_name:                 params[:stripeShippingName],
  stripe_authenticity_token:            params[:authenticity_token],
  stripe_email:                         params[:stripeEmail],
  stripe_billing_address_country_code:  params[:stripeBillingAdressCountryCode],
  stripe_shipping_address_country_code: params[:stripeShippingAdressCountryCode],
  stripe_shipping_address_country:      params[:stripeShippingAdressCountry],
  stripe_billing_address_country:       params[:stripeBillingAdressCountry],
  billing_address:                      params[:stripeBillingAddressLine1],
  billing_city:                         params[:stripeBillingAddressCity],
  billing_state:                        params[:stripeBillingAddressState],
  billing_zip:                          params[:stripeBillingAddressZip],
  shipping_address:                     params[:stripeShippingAddressLine1],
  shipping_city:                        params[:stripeShippingAddressCity],
  shipping_state:                       params[:stripeShippingAddressState],
  shipping_zip:                         params[:stripeShippingAddressZip],
  product_id:                           params[:product_id]
end
```

With a `product_id` of 1 and 2, I get the final result of `product_id` 2.
How do I get all `product_ids` on `Order.create`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this

```
<% @order_items.each do |oi| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_ids[]', oi.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This seems to create a string instead of an integer

Comment: It is okay I think for your purposes. You still can use `find` by `string`.  
`ids = ["1", "2", "3"]`  
`objects = SomeModel.find(ids)`

Comment: And you can always use `to_i` to be sure it is a `integer`. `objects = SomeModel.find(ids.map(&:to_i))`

Comment: I can see both product ids in the charge controller but, for some reason the ids do not pass to the Order create

Comment: In your question you said that `OrderItem` has one `product_id`. And you try to create `Order`. Are you missing something? Or it is me who missing?

Comment: There are multiple order items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115478/discussion-between-aleksey-and-jgrant).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<% @order_items.each do |oi| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_ids[]'.to_i, oi.id %>
<% end %>
```